# jquery multiple images and checkboxes

Tags: jquery, image, checkbox

I am new to jquery but I am familiar with php, perl, a little JS and have been trying to find an answer.

I want to use images in place of checkboxes using jquery. I have a working example that only works for one checkbox. I have tried many variations based on examples I have come across but have not been able to make it work.

Here is the working code I have so far for one check box.

CSS

```
.checked {border:solid 2px red}
```

HTML

```
<img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/windows-8-metro-style/128/unchecked_checkbox.png" title="blr" id="blr" class="" />
<input type="checkbox" id="imgCheck" name="imgCheck" value="barney" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

jQuery Code

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#blr').on('click', function(){
        var $$ = $(this)
        if( !$$.is('.checked')){
            $$.addClass('checked');
            $('#imgCheck').prop('checked', true);
        } else {
            $$.removeClass('checked');
            $('#imgCheck').prop('checked', false);
        }
    })
});
```

I know there is a simple solution and I'm normally pretty good at piecing together code and making it work. Since I am stuck I am guessing I'm not looking for the right thing. If someone could let me know I would really appreciate it.

Comment: What does your code look like when you have multiple images?   Is there a containing div for example?  Do you have different `id`s?  (remember each `id` should be unique on the page)

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

**HTML**

```
<img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/windows-8-metro-style/128/unchecked_checkbox.png" title="blr" id="blr" class="blr" />
<input type="checkbox" class="imgCheck" id="imgCheck" name="imgCheck" value="barney" />
<img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/windows-8-metro-style/128/unchecked_checkbox.png" title="blr" id="blr1" class="blr" />
<input type="checkbox" id="imgCheck1" class="imgCheck" name="imgCheck" value="barney" />
<img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/windows-8-metro-style/128/unchecked_checkbox.png" title="blr" id="blr1" class="blr" />
<input type="checkbox" id="imgCheck2" name="imgCheck" class="imgCheck" value="barney" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.blr').on('click', function(){
        var $$ = $(this)
        if( !$$.is('.checked')){
            $$.addClass('checked');
            $$.next(".imgCheck").prop('checked', true);
        } else {
            $$.removeClass('checked');
            $$.next(".imgCheck").prop('checked', false);
        }
    })
});
```

This will work with multiple check boxes.

You will have to use class selector in JQuery as there are multiple elements so you should not use the same id for each element.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use class selector for multiple check boxes.eg., '.blr' instead of '#blr', Use

```
$(document).on("click", ".blr", function(){
    var $$ = $(this)
    if( !$$.is('.checked')){
        $$.addClass('checked');
        $$.next("input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', true);
    } else {
        $$.removeClass('checked');
        $$.next("input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', false);
    }

})
```

Because `$(document)` will fetch all checkboxes with given class name in the root document. So dynamically added checkboxes also get effects of the event.

Comment: While useful, the question wasn't about event delegation, which has a performance implication.  `.blr` but still `#imgCheck`?

Answer (score 0):

IDs need to be unique on the page, so you can't use IDs for the event or the .ischecked.  Instead, use either `data-` attributes or `class`.

Class is frequently used for style/appearance, but it can also be used to indicate functionality.

This solution wraps the `img` and `input` in a containing div so that related img/input pairs can be matched.  This also allows you to change how the img/inputs are located in the html without relying on fixed constructs such as `.next` which limit how you can arrange your html (more so than using a containing div, which does also limit this to an extent).

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/windows-8-metro-style/128/unchecked_checkbox.png" title="blr" class="clickableimage" />
<input type="checkbox" value="harvey" style='display:none'/>
</div>

<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

jQuery

```
$('.clickableimage').on('click', function() {
    var $$ = $(this);
    if( !$$.is('.checked')){
        $$.addClass('checked');
        $$.closest(".container").find(":input").prop('checked', true);
    } else {
        $$.removeClass('checked');
        $$.closest(".container").find(":input").prop('checked', false);
    }
});
```

Example fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/n98xg57w/